# Razor Syntax not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, razor, google-maps-api-3

I have well over a 136 locations with a latitude and longitude and am trying to create, essentially, a 136 map markers on a good map using java script, razor and C#. Well the issue is, the piece of JavaScript in the razor is not showing up and I am curious if I am doing everything correctly.

```
    var mapMarker;

    @{
        IEnumerable<UFA.Location.Core.Location> Location = UFALocation___Front.Helpers.QueryHelper.QueryHelper.getAllLocations();
        foreach(var loc in Location){
            <text>
                mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(@loc.latitude, @loc.longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: "Hello World!"
                });
            </text>
        }
    }
```

I essentially just loop through all locations and get the latitude and longtitude, the issue is, the markers don't show up because the piece of javascript in the for each, doesn't exist.

full script bellow:

```
function success(position) {
        var s = document.querySelector('#status');

        if (s.className == 'success') {
            // not sure why we're hitting this twice in FF, I think it's to do with a cached result coming back    
            return;
        }

        s.innerHTML = "found you!";
        s.className = 'label label-success';


        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "You are here! (at least within a " + position.coords.accuracy + " meter radius)"
        });

        var mapMarker;

        @{
            IEnumerable<UFA.Location.Core.Location> Location = UFALocation___Front.Helpers.QueryHelper.QueryHelper.getAllLocations();
            foreach(var loc in Location){
                <text>
                    mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(@loc.latitude, @loc.longitude),
                        map: map,
                        title: "Hello World!"
                    });
                </text>
            }
        }

        var SampleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.379, -113.53),
            map: map,
            title: "Hello World!"
        }); 

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var request = {
            origin: latlng,
            destination: '304 304 26th ave sw calgary alberta',
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }

    function error(msg) {
        var s = document.querySelector('#status');
        s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
        s.className = 'alert alert-error';

        // console.log(arguments);
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else {
        error('not supported');
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting a comment to see if anything in the loop is working?

Comment: It doesnt seem to ever go inside the `@{}` as I have break points in there, but printing comments in the `<text></text>` seems to work

Comment: Just for giggles, try putting the 'looped' JavaScript on one line, and use @: instead of <text>.  Ex.  @:mapMarker = new google.maps.Marker(...);

Comment: Doesn't display, its like it never goes in the code block

Comment: Odd.  Have you checked to make certain that getAllLocations() returns values?

Comment: again, I cant even check because break points on it are never caught, as stated I dont think its going into the `@{}` block

Comment: again, run that same method, getAllLocations(), *elsewhere* to verify the data.  Do whatever you have to, to verify the data, but don't get stuck looking at the same code block over and over again.